# Wrong target when pressing html button with html tags in it

Tags: javascript, html

I have four buttons and want to trace which one is pressed. In some of them I changed innerHTML property with HTML tag. Then I noticed that when a button is pressed there is a possability of mouseEvent.target being not a button but the text itself. This only occures when html-tag-modified button is pressed.

Here is a part of the js code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){        
    buttons[i].innerHTML = countries[index]["c"];
    buttons[i].onclick = clickHandler;

}

buttons[correct_btn].innerHTML = "<some-tag>" + countries[target_id]["c"] + "</some-tag>";

function clickHandler(me){
    console.log(me.target);
}
```

I hope I described the problem clearly. I could get away without html tag in buttons, but I still wonder if there is a way to avoid button text being targeted. Or could it be that my approach to trace buttons wrong from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget) instead. From MDN:

> It always refers to the element the event handler has been attached to
>   as opposed to event.target which identifies the element on which the
>   event occurred

```
function clickHandler(me){
    console.log(me.currentTarget);
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Blade0rz/mwyHu/1/) is a fiddle to demonstrate the above.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted to know!